# SharePoint documents in Excel 2016 can only be edited by one user at any one time

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint library containing Excel files. One of the Excel (.xlsx) files is used as a "database" and needs to be edited by multiple users simultaneously. The users don't interact directly with the "database" - a second file uses macros to open, read and write to the "database" and to save it.

Unfortunately, on opening the file, a banner reading "READ-ONLY We opened this workbook read only from the server." appears, along with a button to "Edit Workbook".

The button has the same effect as the vba method "Workbooks.LockServerFile" - which means that if you click this button or open the file programmatically and apply the LockServerFile method, then the workbook can only be edited by the person who opens it until they close the file. Subsequent users get a message saying "This file is locked for editing by USER. Do you want to: [open the document read only or save a copy]".

I have tried various things:

- marked the SharePoint location as a trusted location in MS Trust Centre through Excel
- shared the document with the other users using the the "Share" button in Excel
- marked the document as "open read only" in File -> Info then used VBA to ignore this (with
  IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended = True)

However, the problem persists - only one person at a time can edit our "Share"Point documents.

N.B. I have reviewed the following similar question but no answer has been provided. [Handle "File In Use" dialog box in the code when updatinf files on SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308343/handle-file-in-use-dialog-box-in-the-code-when-updatinf-files-on-sharepoint)

Comment: Sharing =/= collaborating!  If your macro books interact with the source repository, you can keep attempting to open the book to add your info, think `do`, and once it's an editable document, make the changes.  This could take some time to do data entry, but could help with the shortcoming.  Ideally, you would get a proper database.

Comment: Thanks, Cyril. I can't seem to upvote your comment, but thank you all the same. A solution seems to have been found which was due to a license issue with MS Office. Users can now edit the document simultaneously and merge changes.